# copied google sheets and try to fetch data using php but data is not accurate

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I have this file

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-U3zAECz0TNF-yLzNdzfDyuMzRVAcJrc6L8wni1lDhc/edit?usp=sharing

I am copy this file 
and try to get data from this sheet.

```
$tempLoc        = $file;
Yii::import('ext.phpexcel.XPHPExcel');
$objPHPExcel    = XPHPExcel::createPHPExcel();

$inputFileType  = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($tempLoc);
$objReader      = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$ExcelData      = $objReader->load($tempLoc);

$sheet          = $ExcelData->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow     = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn  = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
```

but when i try to get data from this sheet it will display like 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnOhQ.png)

and you can see in sheet header is different from this array,can someone please help me to slove it,

i tried with

```
1.$objReader->setInputEncoding('');
2.$objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-16LE');
```

Comment: If the sheet data is different, then you're not copying the file that you expect, or not loading the file that you believe you're loading.... we can't guess which of those it is; but PHPExcel doesn't have the built-in intelligence to replace on set of dutch? heading texts with another

Comment: have u checked it @mark baker

Comment: becuase i am facing this issue that means somting is wrong on it

Comment: Yes,I have checked your link and image: I can see that the header row from the linked spreadsheet doesn't match the header array that you've displayed that PHPExcel is loading.... but unless PHPExcel has become self-aware and learned german? or whatever language it is, then it hasn't decided to arbitrarily replace the data in the cells with something else

Comment: So my only suggestion is that you're not loading the file that you think you are